# Link opens 2 new windows

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

For some odd reason, my ad at the top (Sign up & win) opens 2 new windows upon clicking. It works fine on Chrome but on FF and Safari, the issue persists.

Website: [View here](http://www.mycitylife.ca)

Any help would be great. The plugin is Advanced Ad

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove or modify the attribute "target='_blank'" from your anchor tag around the ad.  Having target assigned to _blank tells the browser to start a new window session.  Depending on the action you desire you may try removing this attribute all together or using '_self' or '_parent' instead.

More information about this can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: Tested this, emptied cache as well... Issue persists